# What is the grammaticality of "not" in "I hope not" and "I know not"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, archaic-language

This question stemmed from the lyrics of the song [Vague Utopia](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Tia-Gostelow/Vague-Utopia) by [Tia Gostelow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tia_Gostelow). One of the lines from the chorus is as following:

> I just want you to know,
>   And i know **not** what the younger dreams,
>   Some vague utopia, utopia

The structure *I know not what the...* sounded a bit weird to me. After doing some research, the closest similar grammatically valid structures(from oxford) that I found are:

1. Treating the symptoms and not the cause. (negative of *the cause*).
2. How was it? Not so bad. (Not very close to the actual lyrics).

I also think the lyrics could be using archaic English, when *I know not*, *I run not* etc were permissible in English. Please explain if the lyrics is grammatically correct, and if yes, what rule is it using.

Grazie

Comment: Yes, _I know not_ is an archaic construction, presumably used in the song for the sake of the metre. In modern English we would say _I do not know_. However, expressions like _I hope not_ and _I think not_ are different, presumably implying _I hope it is not true_.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. But note that ***I hope not*** remains the "idiomatic standard" for the sense of *I hope it [some contextually-established possibility] is not true*. On the other hand, although ***I think not*** does still occur "naturally" sometimes, it's definitely heading for "archaic" status alongside ***I know not*** sometime in the coming decades.

Answer (score 1):

"I know not" is a bit old-fashioned, but I wouldn't go so far as to call it archaic. [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22I%20know%20not%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20I%20know%20not%20%22%3B%2Cc0) shows something of a decline, but it hasn't vanished.

I'd say it's mostly used in songs and poems